# What is the meaning of two spaces being equal?

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have a problem where i need to show that $F = \mathcal{H}$ where $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbertspace and $F$ is a closed subspace of $\mathcal{H}$. I have worked out through the other information that $F$ is dense in $\mathcal{H}$ and from that i should be able to conclude that $F = \mathcal{H}$, but i don't really understand what it means that two spaces equal each other.

Thanks for reading

Comment: It means that every element of $\mathcal H$ is in $F$. As opposed to $\Bbb Q$ which is dense in $\Bbb R$ but not every real is a rational.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the exercise is to show that $F$ is a dense and  closed subspace in $H$ and conclude that $F$ must coincide with $H$ because $H$ is complete (i.e. there are no closed dense subspaces in $H$ except $H$ itself). It is a standard technique.